# How can I force weasyprint to use the colors in PDF?

Tags: html, pdf, weasyprint

When I use

```
$ weasyprint table.html table.pdf
```

on https://jsfiddle.net/MartinThoma/0hL29mcc/ it generates a PDF which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the heading is black, not red. Also, the table is not striped anymore.

Somehow weasyprint removes all colors. How can I prevent this behaviour / keep the colors? (I don't necessarily need to use weasyprint, but I don't know any better alternative)

I use `WeasyPrint version 0.40`.

### What I've tried

- `pandoc table.html -o table.pdf`: Does not apply CSS page rotation; does not apply CSS
- `wkhtmltopdf table.html out.pdf`:  Does not apply CSS page rotation; (but applies some CSS - not the color, though)
- `import pdfkit;pdfkit.from_file('table.html', 'outpdfkit.pdf')`:  Does not apply CSS page rotation (looks the same as `wkhtmltopdf`)

Comment: I have this issue as well; no colors are applied to the table elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that Bootstrap 3 contains the following:

```
@media print{
    *,:after,:before {
        color:#000!important;
        text-shadow:none!important;
        background:0 0!important;
        -webkit-box-shadow:none!important;
        box-shadow:none!important
    }
}
```

So weasyprint is actually behaving as intended. Removing this leads to the expected results.

Comment: Great! I was using bootstrap externally though, so I ended up adding !important many places, which is not very pretty, but got me the intended results.

Comment: Actually just decided to migrate this specific template to bootstrap 4, which changes this media print query to not affect colors.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well and I have a suitable workaround. At least in my case, it appears to be a conflict between WeasyPrint and Bootstrap. I'm using WeasyPrint from within Python. I reordered my list of CSS files to put my custom CSS first - I thought it needed to go last. Then I added the `!important` modifier to my `color` and `background-color` tags.

For example:

```
@media print {
    bg-blue {
        background-color: #1e77b4 !important;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.